# How do you use the random function on a dictionary within a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, random

Let's say I have a dictionary nested inside a list.

```
data = [
{
    'name': 'Dave',
    'born': 1949
    'country': 'United States'
},
{
    'name': 'Chris',
    'born': 1976,
    'country': 'Portugal'
},
{
    'name': 'Lisa',
    'born': 1983,
    'country': 'United States'
}
       ]
```

Now I want to go through the list and pick a random value from the 'name' key so it can either print out Dave, Chris or Lisa.
I know that I need to loop through the list and use random.choice, but I am not sure how to do it with a dictionary within a list.

Comment: you can use `numpy.random.randint(0, len(data))` to randomly generate an index. Then use that index to get the dictionary and finally the name.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to recognize that you are still working with a list, and the elements of that list are individual dictionaries,

```
import random

data = [
    {
        'name': 'Dave',
        'born': 1949,
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Chris',
        'born': 1976,
        'country': 'Portugal'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Lisa',
        'born': 1983,
        'country': 'United States'
    }
]

for i in range(5):
    temp_dict = random.choice(data)
    print(temp_dict['name'])
```

So you can select a random element using `random.choice` and then use it with any functionality that element provides. Here the element is a dictionary, to print only the `name` key you simply select it, `temp_dict['name']`.